# search in a file in c

Tags: c, search, scanf, fgets

the data on the [file.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OUmE.png)  are placed as shown.

My Code is this:

```
int searchBookname()
{
    FILE *myFile=fopen("file.txt","r+");


    if (myFile!=NULL) // file  exists
    {
        char tmp1[512];
        char tmp2[512];

        while(fgets(tmp1,512,myFile)!=EOF)
        {
            puts("Insert the Book Name: ");
            scanf("%s",tmp2);
            if(strstr(tmp1,tmp2)!=NULL){
                printf("the book is found: %s\n\n",tmp1);
            }else{
                puts("\nSorry there was no Match with this name! Maybe Book is not recorded yet :(\n");
            }
        }

    }else{ // file doesn't exist
        puts("\nDatabase is not created yet. Please record a new book to create a simple database\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    fclose(myFile); // closing the file
}
```

It keeps skipping the if statement 2 times for some reason and on the 
3rd time it prints the correct result.
This happen for whatever book I try to search.
See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6IKO.png)

How can I make it find the result without skipping the if statement.

Comment: You read the file line by line. So in the third loop/line there is a record with 'book1'. Code is working correctly. Maybe you want to ask the user for a book name outside of the while loop and search in every line for the given book name. If there is, you can print you message and break from the loop.

Comment: I tried your code but it cannot read from that image. Voting to Close as "not locally reproducable". (And even if I create a dummy file.txt, it does not seem to produce an image so that part is also not reproducable.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem (including any necessary inputs, but preferably not needing any), then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read the file line by line. So in the third loop/line there is a record with 'book1'. Code is working correctly as it is. Maybe you want to ask the user for a book name outside of the while loop and search in every line for the given book name. If there is, you can print you message and break from the loop.

```
int searchBookname()
    {
        FILE *myFile=fopen("file.txt","r+");

        if (myFile != NULL) // file  exists
        {
            char tmp1[512], tmp2[512];

            puts("Insert the Book Name: ");
            scanf("%s",tmp2);

            // Skip the first two lines of the file
            fgets(tmp1,512,myFile);
            fgets(tmp1,512,myFile);

            while(fgets(tmp1,512,myFile) != EOF)
            {
                if(strstr(tmp1,tmp2) != NULL)
                {
                    printf("the book is found: %s\n\n",tmp1);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    puts("\nSorry there was no Match with this name! Maybe Book is not recorded yet :(\n");
                }
            }

        }
        else
        { // file doesn't exist
            puts("\nDatabase is not created yet. Please record a new book to create a simple database\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        fclose(myFile); // closing the file
    }
```

Comment: this doesnt happen only with "book1", i.e it happens also with "book5".
If I ask user outside while loop, it won't repeat in case of user typed it wrong.

Comment: You can add a do-while loop to ensure that the user inputs a correct book name based on some personal criteria. In your way, for each line you read, you ask the user to re-entry the book name.

Comment: You are welcome. You can also remove the else statement inside the while loop, as it will result to unnecessary prints. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious.
First 2 lines of file are following:

```
Record_Date ...
-> (empty line)
```

You are reading file line by line and check book name in each line. So `if` must fail for first 2 times.
If you want to find a book in your file, your approach is incorrect. There are different approaches for this, but simplest is reading book records into an structure array, and then look for book name in that array.